# LuaTeX: Microtype/fontspec/luaotfload buggy interaction canceling each other's settings

Tags: spacing, color, fontspec, microtype, luaotfload

Microtype and fontspec/luaotfload seem to interact, and cancel each other's settings. In the following code, fontspec option `Color=FF0000` and `\lsstyle` interact to cancel each others effect (coloring & spacing). Luaotfload gives weird error message:

> `luaotfload | color : "ff0000ffkernfactor" is not a valid rgb[a] color expression`

Code: Run it two times, first without any changes to see the color & spacing effects being canceled. For the second run do the changes (comment/uncomment) mentioned in code. It seems to hide the error exposed in Run-1, but its not a solution as option Color can take other named colors values like `Color=red` **where we cannot do anything!**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\SetTracking[name=body,spacing={-10*,1*,1*}]{encoding=*}{-20}

% Run-1: keep following line uncommented, Run-2: comment following line
\setmainfont[Color=FF0000]{Linux Libertine O}

% Run-1: keep following line commented, Run-2: uncomment following line
%\setmainfont[Color=FF0000FF]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
    \lsstyle 
    \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of Run-1: Spacing does not change from default, and coloring is not applied
[image: Output of Run-1]
Screenshot of Run-2: Spacing gets tighter, and coloring is applied
[image: Output of Run-2]

Comment: looks like a fontspec bug, in your first example it forgets to end the color with a semicolon, but in the second example it is there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's more of a microtype bug actually. Fontspec adds `FF ` (with a final space) to the color if no transparency is provided (The final space is weird, but technically legal). microtype on the other hand assumes that fontnames never contain a space and contain a final semicolon and therefore breaks.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger but fontspec reports a wrong feat string (the semicolon is missing)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger ah no you are right, the semicolon is there, only on the next line. But it would probably better if fontspec would remove it? Or is there a reason to keep it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think there is (I had some issues with this before when I accidentially forbid it while changing some color stuff) but it is explicitily inserted with `FF~` so there must have been some reason at some point. In any case microtype should be changed too because there might be other spaces in a fontname.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I can add an issue for fontspec later, perhaps you can inform microtype as you seem to know where in its code it fails?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I'll do so.

Comment: This has been fixed in `microtype` v3.0.